# supremum/infimum clarification, correction?

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking at some examples of evaluating suprema and infima, but I believe there may be a mistake-- either that or I am misunderstanding something.

The examples in the notes say:

$ A = \{  x \in \mathbb{R} : x^{2} < \pi\}$ , then $inf(A) = -\sqrt{3} $ , $sup (A) = \sqrt{3}$

$ E = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x^{2} < \pi\}$, then $inf(E) = -\sqrt{3}$ ,  $sup (E) = \sqrt{3}$

However, I am pretty sure the first one is $inf(A) = -\sqrt{\pi}$ ,  $sup (A) = \sqrt{\pi}$, and the second is also $inf(E) = -\sqrt{\pi}$ ,  $sup (E) = \sqrt{\pi}$. However, neither sets have a max or a min. Is what I am saying correct? Also, what should I be considering when we make the switch for a subset $A$  of $\mathbb{R}$ to a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Edit: Okay, I am not sure about the Sup/Inf of the second subset $E$. The answers I gave don't even belong to the superset $\mathbb{Q}$. I think that the set $E$ has no $Sup/Inf$ since they have no least upper bound/greatest lower bound.

Comment: Maybe $\pi$ was a typo for $3$?

Comment: So I am right? Is what I say in my edit correct?

Comment: Why do you assume E has Q as its "superspace"?

Comment: After all both $A $ and $B $ have $(-\sqrt {\pi},\sqrt {\pi}) $ as supersets.  And the points don't exist in that superset either.

Answer (score 5):

The question as stated is too vague to be answered correctly: the answer depends on the space your subsets belong to. For example, if $A$ and $E$ are taken to be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\inf(A) = \inf(E) = -\sqrt{\pi}$ and $\sup(A) = \sup(E) = \sqrt{\pi}$. However, if $E$ is taken to be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, then your edit is correct and the set $E$ doesn't have an infimum or supremum. Remember that infima/suprema don't need to belong to the subsets themselves, but they do need to belong to the space that the subsets are considered to be part of. And you are correct that both subsets do not have a maximum or minimum since those values would need to belong to the subsets themselves.

Just because $E$ is defined as $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x^2 < \pi\}$ and you see the $\mathbb{Q}$ in the set builder notation does not automatically imply that you have to consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as the space $E$ belongs to. You would write the same definition if you considered $E$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ if you wanted $E$ to contain all (and only) rational numbers whose square is less than $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I suspected. I did not know what to think of the space that E belonged to. You've made that very clear, thank you.

Comment: Both A and B can belong to the space $(-\sqrt \pi,\sqrt \pi) $.  In which case the sup and info don't exist.  Or they could both belong to the space $(-\sqrt \pi,\infty)$ in which case they both haves sup but neither have infs.

Comment: Technically, you don't know what space A belongs to either.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your space is $\mathbb R $ (if you don't specify the universal space the question is unanswerable) than $A $ is the open interval of all real numbers between $-\sqrt \pi $ and $\sqrt \pi$.  $E$ is the set of all rationals in the interval.

It makes absolutely no difference whatsoever whether sets are defined to be real, rational, integers, complex, or numbers with "a" in them when spoken in Arabic.

All that matters is whether the sets do or do not have least upper and greatest lower bounds.

So is $E$ bounded below?  Yes, $-4$  is a lower bound.  Is there a number that is a lower bound so that any number larger than it is not a lower bound? Yes, $-\sqrt \pi $ is lesser than any point in $E $.  If $x >-\sqrt {\pi}$ then there is a rational number $q $ so the $q <x $ and $q^2<\pi$.  So $-\sqrt \pi =\inf E $.

Same questions of $A $.  Same answers.

Did they *have* to be the same answers? No.  But they were.

Notice if $C= \{-\sqrt{\pi}\}\cup \{\frac 1 {n+1}|n\in \mathbb Z\}\cup [2,\sqrt {\pi}) $ and $D=\{\sqrt\pi,-\sqrt \pi\} $ will have the exact same $\inf$ and $\sup $ despite being a nearly entirely different sets from either $A $ nor $E $ or each other.

Comment: This is why I was confused-- the notes on pdf were not clear and this is what I suspected.